# Azure mobile services offline sync not deleting offline when also adding the item offline

Tags: c#, azure, mvvm, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile services to sync offline data in a wpf mvvm app.
When the app is online CRUD works fine, but when going offline and adding a new record and deleting it wil give this Error:

> Message = "The item is in inconsistent state in the local store. Please complete the pending sync by calling PushAsync() before deleting the item."

I also tried purging the record but it will return

> The table cannot be purged because it has pending operations.

Deleting:

```
            try
            {
                await _client.GetSyncTable<TEntity>().DeleteAsync(Model);
                await _client.SyncAsync();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invex)
            {
                var query = _client.GetSyncTable<TEntity>().CreateQuery().Where(el => el.Id == Model.Id);
                await _client.GetSyncTable<TEntity>().PurgeAsync($"purgeEtBla", query,true,CancellationToken.None);
                await _client.SyncAsync();
            }
```

Adding:

```
 var entity = _mapper.Map<TEntity>(EntityViewModel);
 await _client.GetSyncTable<TEntity>().InsertAsync(entity);
 _list.AddEntity(entity);
 window?.Close();
 await _client.SyncAsync();
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue did you find a solution?

Comment: I have not found a proper solution yet, It is possible to delete the item manually from the local sql db but that is kinda ugly.